# An entrance to... What am I?

Tags: riddle

> People enter for many reasons
>
> Yet leave for better or worse
>
> I hold the stories, greedy seasons
>
> Sadly, I know not a verse
>
> But I would if I'd lived as a tree

What am I?

Hint:

> I am helpful

Edit:

Hint 2:

> Greed is important

Hint 3:

> Tree does reference paper

Hint 4:

> I am an object not a place

Hint 5:

> I'm often used every day

Comment: I've added 5 hints hopefully I've un broadened it enough to guess.  Sorry I made this one so difficult guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I ..

> Verbal agreement

People enter for many reasons

> People enter into an agreement for many reasons

Yet leave for better or worse

I hold the stories, greedy seasons

> If someone breaks it, its usually that he is better off without it, and maybe because of his personal greed.

Sadly, I know not a verse

But I would if I'd lived as a tree

> A verbal agreement is not written anywhere, thus no one can prove it even existed

OR

Am I ..

> A Shredder

--EDIT--

> A toilet seat, people enter for many reasons(duh!), greedy season(for sure, everyone enters for their personal greed). It' helpful, used often everyday, greed is important(why would anyone sit on it otherwise). OR Maybe its the "Iron Throne", who knows.

Comment: great guess, not what I had in mind so I've added an extra hint

Comment: @Jason_ This sure has a lot of things associated to the possibilities of being.

Comment: okay I admit this was not my best riddle.  I'll say you answered it scince you tried pretty hard and post what I was trying to say

Answer (score 3):

You can be

> War

People enter for many reasons

> For freedom, sources etc.

Yet leave for better or worse

> Only one side wins

I hold the stories, greedy seasons

> War stories

Sadly, I know not a verse

But I would if I'd lived as a tree

> Truce or deals?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Thanks for using spoilers and explaining your answer! c:

Comment: Really nice guess +1.  I like the thought put into it, but the answer is not right

Comment: @Jason_  then I would really appreciate a new hint if it's possible.

Comment: @KeithN, added hint

Comment: @Deusovi hi again! I think I can't comment on other posts if I don't answer right?

Comment: @KeithN: You can comment anywhere when you get 50 reputation - that means you just need two more upvotes on an answer, or four more on a question.

Answer (score 1):

Are You

> A Book (or) A Paper.

Because, People enter for many reasons

> People Read Books for Many Reasons.

Yet leave for better or worse

> There are many good and bad books as they were helpful (or) boring.

I hold the stories, greedy seasons

> Books holds stories and seasons things.

Sadly, I know not a verse

> Books doesn't know it had a verse.

But I would if I'd lived a tree

> Papers are made from trees.

Hint: I am Helpful

> Books are always helpful.

Comment: Good reasoning and it fits rather well, but that's not what I am.

Comment: My bad..I am thinking again to find it.

Comment: Probably answer is Library.

Comment: @RamVisagan don't worry about it, I did think it could fit a book as I wrote it out though (:

Comment: Yeah.. But that isn't issue... I will search for another better answer..

Comment: @Jason_ Then be warned: It may be closed as 'Too broad' if there are enough answers that fit.

Answer (score 0):

Because It had so many answers and was quite broad I thought I'd share my thoughts:

What I wanted to be was

> A wallet

People enter for many reasons

> Put money away, pay, show ID

Yet leave for better or worse

> You can close your wallet with more money or less

I hold the stories, greedy seasons

> Money is used in many greedy situations

Sadly, I know not a verse

> It's describing the wallet, the wallet only holds the money

But I would if I'd lived as a tree

> It would experience the same if it had been made into money